# On zooming a JQplot chart, make the y axis values integers

Tags: jquery, zooming, jqplot, axis

On zooming the `jqPlot` chart, the number of decimal places in the y axis values keep increasing and as a result even the axis label gets pushed out of the screen.
Is it possible to limit the values to integers or use notations such as 1K etc if the number of digits is too large.

Specifying **formatString: '%d'** in tickOptions didn't help, since, on zoom, the values are recalculated.

```
yaxis: {
    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
    tickOptions: {
        fontSize: this.sYAxisTickFontSize,
        formatString: '%d'
    }
}​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested what you are saying and you are right the values are recalculated but the format is always being applied. [You can see it in the sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/zALuD/3/). It shows that the zoom doesn't increase the number of decimal places, as it always applies the specified `formatString: '%d'`.

Please check out the code sample and see if you do not have other issues somewhere. Best if you still have the problem post a jsfiddle presenting your issue.